# Hibernate Query doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, hibernate, nhibernate

Hi i have the following Query:

```
 String hql = "UPDATE Raumreservierung as rr " +
              "set VON = :begin " +
              "where VON = :Von " +
              "and Raum_ID IN (SELECT r.ID FROM Raum r " +
              "inner join r.Panel as pl with pl.ID = " + clientId + "";



 IQuery query = CurrentSession.CreateQuery(hql);
                query.SetParameter("begin", DateTime.Now);
                query.SetParameter("Von", v.Von);
                int result = query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

The Query do an Update on "VON". That works fine, but the rest of the Query is not working. It seems that the rest of the query is not working. But did not get any Error.

With the rest of the Query i mean the following part of the query:

```
"and Raum_ID IN (SELECT r.ID FROM Raum r " +
"inner join r.Panel as pl with pl.ID = " + clientId + "";
```

Because it should happen only a Update on the column "VON" for example when "clientId" is "AT2"
But that part is not working. Because the update happens also on other clientId.

Comment: What do you mean "Query do an Update on VON" - does it update field named VON? Does it update a correct number (subset) of records? Which "rest of the Query is not working"?

Comment: You should really explain this better. What is the "rest of the query"? It doesn't do `where` part correctly? Also, you have an additional parameter set - "Bis". It's not mentioned in HQL query above.

Comment: Look the exact query send to your database (http://nhprof.com/) and try it in SQL Server Manager Studio (if you use SQL Server)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close your parentheses.

(Also, you should use a parameter for clientId too)

Comment: hi if i set a paramter for clientId like       query.SetParameter("PanelId", clientId); iam getting an Error: could not locate name Parameter [PanelId]Stack

Comment: Um... you need to declare the parameter first... instead of concatenating a string.

Comment: if :von is a string, in the query that should be this : "where VON = ':Von' " +